# Crashes on sizeWithFont and its replacement on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, ios7, sizewithfont

I have the application that uses `sizeWithFont` method. It crashes on about 5% of launches of the application on iOS 7. The method is deprecated on SDK 7, so I replaced it with the following category:

```
#import "NSString+mySizeWithFont.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation NSString (mySizeWithFont)

- (CGSize)mySizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font {
    if (is_iOS7) {
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT);
        return [self mySizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size];
    } else {
        return [self sizeWithFont:font];
    }
}

- (CGSize)mySizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (is_iOS7) {
        NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
        CGRect frame = [self boundingRectWithSize:size options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];
        return frame.size;
    } else {
        return [self sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size];
    }
}

@end
```

But now I have another crashes on the same 5% of launches. There are crash reports of 2 types:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0005006f
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3902cb76 objc_msgSend + 22
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec74c56 +[__NSDictionaryI __new:::::] + 358
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec749c6 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 238
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec794d4 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:] + 372
4   *** MYAPP ***                   0x000cd99e -[NSString(mySizeWithFont) mySizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:] (NSString+mySizeWithFont.m:25)
5   *** MYAPP ***                   0x000cd7e6 -[NSString(mySizeWithFont) mySizeWithFont:] (NSString+mySizeWithFont.m:17)
6   *** MYAPP ***                   0x000d36ae -[LiteVersionHomepageLink drawRect:] (LiteVersionHomepageLink.m:43)
```

And this one:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2ed36e86 __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x390316c2 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ed3a7b2 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 198
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ed390b2 ___forwarding___ + 702
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec87e94 __forwarding_prep_0___ + 20
5   UIFoundation                    0x3660790e __NSStringDrawingEngine + 2950
6   UIFoundation                    0x36606d5a -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 130
7   *** MYAPP ***                   0x000e89d4 -[NSString(mySizeWithFont) mySizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:] (NSString+mySizeWithFont.m:26)
8   *** MYAPP ***                   0x000e87e6 -[NSString(mySizeWithFont) mySizeWithFont:] (NSString+mySizeWithFont.m:17)
9   *** MYAPP ***                   0x000ee6ae -[LiteVersionHomepageLink drawRect:] (LiteVersionHomepageLink.m:43)
```

LiteVersionHomepageLink is inherited from UIView:

```
@interface LiteVersionHomepageLink : UIView {
    NSString *text;
    UIFont *textFont;
}
```

And `mySizeWithFont` is called from the following method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cal_top_back@2x"] drawInRect:rect];
    if (text && textFont) {
        [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
        float height = [text mySizeWithFont:textFont].height / 2;
        [text drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height / 2  - height, rect.size.width, rect.size.height / 2 + height) withFont:textFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    }
}
```

What's wrong? How to fix crashes? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: You can still use `sizeWithFont:` under iOS 7. Since your Base SDK is something other than iOS 7, you won't even get a deprecation warning.

Comment: I'm using SDK 7 with Deployment target 5. But the problem is the crashes - on the deprecated version and on the replacement. On any way I have 5% of crashes on the application's launch.

Comment: Get rid of your `is_iOS7` check and replace it with a proper check for the existence of the `boundingRectWithSize...` method.

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown in the second case?

Comment: rmaddy, 5% of crashes are on the same device (with iOS 7 installed).

Comment: All of the crashes suggest some kind of memory management problem to me.  If you turn on zombies, do you get any better information related to this category?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `sizeWithFont` method, you have a memory management problem.  The heap is probably corrupted.  You're getting a crash when `sizeWithFont` tries to allocate a new `NSDictionary` on the heap.

Comment: progrmr, I see crash only on these lines of code. Memory works fine on all other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're calling your routine mySizeWithFont with an invalid font.  Either one that has been released, or one that was never allocated.  I'd put in NSLog breadcrumbs near your font allocation and just before the breadcrumbs to make sure your font is allocated first.  If it is, it may be that ARC is tossing your font before you go to use it - may need @property(strong) or something like that.

Comment: But I can see a crash on the same steps as works on 95% of times.

Comment: It's probably ARC which is indeterminate on when it actually releases your memory. I'll bet sometimes it tosses your font before it gets used here.  Try creating the UIFont object in the object it's used - that should clear your troubles.

Comment: I've added NSZombies and don't see any error with textFont. Why? I don't use ARC.

Comment: Instead of sending the font object, send down the name and size of the font object and allocate it locally in your method.  If that works, it means the font object is either autoreleased and getting munged before you get it here, or you're releasing it somewhere before it gets here.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents: I had, in my app, an overrelease bug with a `UIFont` object. I'd invoke `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:]` and store the result in a file-static variable without retaining.

Up until iOS 7, I'd get away with it, then crashes in `[sizeWithFont]` started coming. Looks like iOS<7 would return font instances from a pool or a cache, so that a single unmatched `release` won't deallocate them. In iOS 7 - not anymore.